# Assign different websites to different networks on apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, networking

I have an apache server running on UBUNTU linux. There are two websites published on apache.The first one in the path /var/www/html/Xsite/. The second in the path /var/www/html/Ysite/. The server have two interfaces, first for management and second for internet. The server is published on the internet using the second interface and any one can access all websites on the server using this interface.
I need to make Ysite only available to the management interface (10.94.133.*) so if I try to open this site through internet, it will be not available. If I open it from inside my company, it will work.
Appreciate your help regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restrict access to your *YSite* to a given IP address (or rather IP address range here), you'll need:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 10.94.133
```

You'll need to put this, ideally, in the relevant `<VirtualHost>` directive in your Apache *httpd-vhosts.conf* file or failing that in an *.htaccess* file in the docroot of */var/www/html/Ysite/*

Comment: Thank you man. After reading, I have got that using .htaccess will impact the apache server negatively so it is better to make it global configuration if it is your own server.